# Isometry Group of real Hilbert space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, topological-groups

Does the isometry group of a *real* separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space have two connected components? Or, conversely, is the there even a Kuiper's theorem in the real case?

How does the isometry group of a real infinite-dimensional Hilbert separable look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is contractible, according to [Kuiper himself](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=179792) who also writes:

> Putnam and Wintner [[5](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=41848), [6](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=45121)] proved with the help of spectral resolutions that $U_{\mathbf R}$ and hence $GL_{\mathbf R}$ are connected.